# ASP.NET Core userManager and context in separated controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to create separated controller only for userManager and dbcontext.
I want to inherit from this controller.
I don't want to inject dependencies using constructor because in that way I would have to add constructor also to another controllers.
Is another way to do this?

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private ApplicationDbContext _context;

ApplicationDbContext Context
{
    get
    {
        if(this._context == null)
        {
            // GET CONTEXT <= HOW TO DO THIS?
        }
        return this._context;
    }
}

UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
{
    get
    {
        if(this._userManager == null)
        {
            // GET USER MANAGER <= HOW TO DO THIS?
        }
        return this._userManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are completely against using Dependency Injection, you can use the Service Locator pattern, but I would advise against it for the reasons detailed in [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

If you *still* don't want to use Dependency Injection, you can use [`HttpContext.RequestServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestservices?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to access an [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) instance and use its [`GetRequiredService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method to request the types you're after, like this:

```
ApplicationDbContext Context
{
    get
    {
        if (this._context == null)
        {
            this._context = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        }

        return this._context;
    }
}

UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
{
    get
    {
        if (this._userManager == null)
        {
            this._userManager = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        }

        return this._userManager;
    }
}
```